# "apple-mobile-web-app" with facebook like button blank screen

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-login, iphone-standalone-web-app

i am trying to build a mobile web app which includes a facebook-like-button for a certain facebook page and on which one can also logout from facebook.

so far i achieved all, except with the small problem that the like-button (if not logged in) opens a new page in safari/ios and after logging in, it does not return to the initial page from were his was called from.

i tried out many solutions from this forum but none applied 100% to my problem, so i dont have a real solution yet...

here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<title>TEST WEB APP</title> 
</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

var m_appId = '1234567890123456';
var m_appUrl = 'http://www.something.com/testapp/';

(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=" + m_appId;
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function logout() {
  FB.logout(function(response) {
  // user is now logged out
  });
}

function fbLogoutUser() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response && response.status === 'connected') {
          FB.logout(function(response) {
              document.location.reload();
          });
      }
  });
}

</script>
<h1>LIKE US!</h1> 
<div class="fb-like" target="_self" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/somepage" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="250" data-show-faces="false"></div>
<button style="display:block; margin-top:25px;" onclick="javascript:fbLogoutUser();">Logout from Facebook</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just found this as an alternative solution: https://github.com/mrmoses/jQuery.stayInWebApp as well as the use of <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui" /> ... will try both as soon as i get hold of the ipad. anybody any experience with those two?

Comment: ... minimal-ui no longer supported for iOS 8 ... damn

Comment: so far i tried many different solution and alternatives (like not using “apple-mobile-web-app” at all, but instead autoscrolling to a point where the browser hides most clutter on top and then blocking scrolling = but this still opens a new window / tab for the fb login, and upon reverting back to the webapp, the browserclutter on top is there again...)... this is so unsatisfying!

Comment: maybe i should try to rephrase my question:

is there a way to force the facebook login, which opens after clicking on the facebook like button, to open on the same page (modal or whatever else?) = here i found some solutions for directly using the fb login but the would not apply (or i dont know how to apply them) as i am using the fb like button...